# How to parallelize Total[]?

Tags: parallelization

I have a list of length ~10^4, with each element being a power series (SeriesData expression). The list has been computed by an earlier part of the code, but I'd like to sum up the list. The Total function is the appropriate one, except that it is not parallelized. For example, to use 4 CPU cores, one might want to split the list into 4 sub-lists, and use each CPU to sum up one sub-list, before adding the 4 results together. Is there something like ParallelTotal[] which can do the job?

Comment: Use Partition, ParallelMap with Total, and Total again. Do benchmark it, there is no guarantee that this will give you a real speedup. I would expect such symbolic expressions to take a long time to transfer to subkernels, maybe even long enough to negate any benefit of parallelization.

Comment: You may also use ParallelCombine to do the same more concisely.

Comment: This sounds like a possible XY problem. Depending on the coefficients there may be faster ways than you have in mind. Certainly if floating-point results are okay.

Comment: Some clarifications: do they need to stay `SeriesData` or can you use `Normal`? What is the format of the list? I whether is it a “column” or a “row”, why not treat it like a vector and `Dot` it with a vector of equal length of all 1’s?